# A pascal's triangle problem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve this pascal's triangle problem. It asks to this:
"Moving only up or to the right, how many paths exist from point A to point B?"

I used the standard method to solve this and got a maze looking like this:

[image]

I got the answer 10 and am wondering if I was supposed to at the 6 and the 4 or the 6 and the 5. Can someone please alleviate the confusion.

Here is the actual problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have added the $5$. Every vertex where two paths up and to the right meet gets the sum of the weight of those two paths; every other vertex has either only an upward path or only a rightward path incoming and inherits the weight of that path. Every path has the weight of its lower or leftmost vertex. The two paths that meet at the top right have weights $6$ and $5$. If you add the $6$ and the $4$ instead, you’re not counting the path that goes right all the way to the bottom right corner and then up.

Comment: Thank you, that helped!